# Filtering in react-widgets combobox: Exact match shows whole list instead of matching item

Tags: javascript, react-widgets

On the [react-widgets example page](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/Combobox/), on typing "Jase" the list gets filtered and only the exact match is visible.

In my project and also the following snippet however, on having typed "Test 1", I see the whole list instead of the one matching entry.

How can I configure the combo box to show only the matching entry instead of the whole list?

```js
let { Combobox } = ReactWidgets;

ReactDOM.render(
    <Combobox
      data={['Test 1','Test 2','3rd element']}
      suggest={false}
      filter="contains"
    />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-widgets/4.5.0/react-widgets.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-widgets/4.5.0/css/react-widgets.css">
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it a bit, I noticed, that the only difference between your example, and the example on their website is, that they use an array of objects as data and you use an array of strings.

And it turned out, that if you type in a Text that matches both the value and the text of an option, it has the unwanted behavior. But in the example on the website, the actual values of the options are numbers and this case cannot happen.

I'm not sure if this is a bug of the component, or if it is expected behavior. But as a workaround, you could create a Wrapper component that turns your string array into an object array, and backwards. Something like this:

```
function ComboboxWrapper({data,onChange,textField,...rest}){
  const wrappedData = data.map((text,value)=>({text,value}))
    return React.createElement(Combobox,{
    data:wrappedData,
    onChange:(c)=>{
      onChange && onChange(typeof c=="object"?c.text:c)
    },
    textField:"text",
    ...rest
   })
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udoakw3x/) for demonstration